# Creating a dictionary of class objects with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, function, dictionary, class

I am trying to create a dictionary of class objects. If I do it one at a time, it works. If I try and use multithreading I end up with an empty dictionary.

This works for one item:

```
import concurrent

this_dict = {}
item_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']

class bot:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.value = 1

def create_bots(item):
    this_dict[item] = bot()

create_bots('test')
```

But, if I use the below example I end up with an empty dictionary. How can I do this?

```
import concurrent

this_dict = {}
item_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']

class bot:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.value = 1
    

def create_bots(item):
    this_dict[item] = bot()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(1)
    futures = [executor.submit(create_bots, item) for item in item_list]
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is a little bit more complicated than it needs to be:

You can write:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    executor.map(create_bots, item_list)
```

When you use `with ThreadPoolExecutor`, `shutdown(wait=True)` is automatically called before the `with` statement finishes.  This means that when the `with` statement is done, you can guarantee that all the processes have finished.

Comment: Well shit, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it, spent probably 6 hours trying to figure it out, asked the question and then stumbled on an article. The below replaces the existing PoolExecutor.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(create_bots, item) for item in item_list]
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```